# How to find the child class name from base class?

Tags: c#, reflection, inheritance

At `run-time`, inside `base class`, how to find the current child class name ?

Comment: What does "current child class name" mean?

Comment: Yes, many children inherit the `base class` and I want the current who is using the `base class`

Comment: If you want to know the actual class you can use the `is` operator e.g. `if (this is BaseClass1) { some code here }`

Comment: @Xaq you have typo in Austin name, he won't get notification.. you can have only @Aus to reduce chances for such typo. :)

Comment: @Austin: Consider a lot of work encapsulated in a single base class to reduce redundancy, then when I gonna Log something in base class, how to do it ?

Comment: That's normally called a "subclass" not a "child class".

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Get the type of the current object, then its name.

```
this.GetType().Name
```

Comment: For base class you can use: `this.GetType().BaseType.Name`

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for partial classes. You get a GUID type number added after the name of the Class.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
Type type = this.GetType().UnderlyingSystemType;  
String className = type.Name;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: thanks Andrew for letting me know. :) my blog site though is just my personal note because I tend to forget things.. nothing about promotion or getting user hits. not even worried if someone would view or comment on it. 

will take note of the rules. many thanks! :)

Answer (score 12):

If you call `this.GetType()` you'll always get the current runtime type regardless of the base class you're inheriting from.